# Difference between IS-LM-UIP and IS-LM-BP models?

Tags: macroeconomics, open-economy-macro

My query is regarding the Mundell-Fleming model. I am reading the chapters on open-economy macroeconomics from Blanchard (I am following Blanchard mainly and I have read all the previous chapters). In Blanchard, the analysis of open-economy issues is done using the IS-LM-UIP model. Blanchard writes "**The model presented here retains the spirit of the original Mundell-Fleming model but
differs in its details**". I checked some other books like those by Dornbusch and Fischer and Froyen.  They have done the analysis using IS-LM-BP model. Can somebody tell me the difference between the two models? Is it possible to do all the analysis that can be done using IS-LM-BP model using IS-LM-UIP model? How much does Blanchard's version differ from the Mundell-Fleming model and the IS-LM-BP model?